# Searching for multiple terms in a cell - matrix

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use this equation to categorize individual rows according to respective keywords inside of a cell in excel.

=INDEX(picklist!$I$6:$I$15;MATCH(TRUE;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(picklist!$J$6:$J$14;K3));0))

where the categories are listed in picklist!I6:I$5
the keywords in picklist!J6:J14
and the text to be searched for is in row K

This equation searches for the presence of a keyword, if it exists, it displays the respective category.

All I'd like to do is search for more than one term/keyword at a time. Anyone know how to add an OR function into this and where to add the other keywords (e.g. same or different cell) so that in the presence of any of these keywords the correct category will be choosen.

Comment: Can you share images of the data in columns I and J on the picklist and row K?

Comment: What if you turn around the search value's cell and search range withing `SEARCH`?